# UIPickerController iPad capture cropping size

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipickerview

I used a very popular code to capture photo with iPad

```
-(void)presentImagePicker:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)source sender:(UIButton *)sender
        {
        if (!self.popOver && [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:source])
        {
            NSArray *availableMedia = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:source];
            if ([availableMedia containsObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeImage])
            {

                UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                picker.delegate = self;
                picker.sourceType = source;
                picker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString*)kUTTypeImage];
                picker.allowsEditing = YES;
                if (source != UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera &&
                    UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
                {
                    self.popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
                    [self.popOver presentPopoverFromRect:sender.bounds
                                                  inView:sender
                                permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                                animated:YES];
                    self.popOver.delegate = self;
                }
                else
                {
                    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
                }
            }
        }
        }
```

The problem is that when the picker shows up, the cropping-size of the capture image is different from the size of the iPad (full screen). It is like a box centered in the screen.
When I take the picture in portrait mode, the captured image is not the portrait image, but something different in size.
My application can run only in landscape mode: is that the problem?

Comment: I tried a solution by adding picker.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(4, 4); No luck

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here

[GKImage picker](https://github.com/gekitz/GKImagePicker)

a custom picker, very very useful.